# Cannot start site on IIS-Express

Tags: windows-7, virtual-memory

**Some background:**
I Am developing a website that uses a BI layer that relays on Matlab.

In order to make the logic layer available across my site I am creating it when the site starts (in `Global.asax.cs`) and storing it in the `Application` object.

**The problem:**
When I initialize the logics object and Matlab tries to starts I get the following error (from *Matlab*):

[image: The Error message by Matlab]

By the error message, it seems that I have some kind of a memory limitation that causes the operation to fail.

**Progress so far:**
After reading a bit, I tried looking into `applicationhost.config` and `aspnet.config` but did not find anything that i thought was related.

Please note that on the same computer I am able to perform the same action in non web context successfully.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: We don't consider client OS development 'servers' to be topical here. I really do think you'd get a better audience for this on [so] too after all they use java ans windows 7 much more than sysadmins.

Comment: I thought since it is an IIS related issue, this would be the right place. I'll post it there as well, If it will get any attention I will delete this post. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You should not cross-post to different sites. Instead, wait until it gets migrated by the community